# I keep getting the error "E/Network: searchBooks: Failed Getting books" but I am not sure why

Tags: android, rest, kotlin, retrofit

So I am using the Google's API and for some reason, I'm getting a generic error:

```
E/Network: searchBooks: Failed Getting books
```

When it initially loads up, the hard coded query "android" shows up with a list of books associated with the book topic. But when I search up a different topic like "shoes" for example, the error shows up. Even when you hard code a different topic other than "android", it still shows the error. I have checked the API and it is working properly with the different query searches.

Here's the Retrofit Interface:

```
@Singleton
interface BooksApi {
    @GET(BOOK_EP)
    suspend fun getAllBooks(
        //don't initialize the query, so that the whole api is available to the user
        @Query("q") query: String
    ): Book

    @GET("$BOOK_EP/{bookId}")
    suspend fun getBookInfo(
        @Path("bookId") bookId: String
    ): Item
}
```

The Repo

```
class BookRepository @Inject constructor(private val api: BooksApi) {

    suspend fun getBooks(searchQuery: String): Resource<List<Item>> {
        return try {
            Resource.Loading(data = true)

            val itemList = api.getAllBooks(searchQuery).items
            if(itemList.isNotEmpty()) Resource.Loading(data = false)
            Resource.Success(data = itemList)
        }catch (exception: Exception){
            Resource.Error(message = exception.message.toString())
        }
    }

    suspend fun getBookInfo(bookId: String): Resource<Item>{
        val response = try {
            Resource.Loading(data = true)
            api.getBookInfo(bookId)
        }catch (exception: Exception){
            return Resource.Error(message = "An error occurred ${exception.message.toString()}")
        }
        Resource.Loading(data = false)
        return Resource.Success(data = response)
    }
```

The ViewModel:

```
class SearchViewModel @Inject constructor(private val repository: BookRepository): ViewModel(){

    var list: List<Item> by mutableStateOf(listOf())
    var isLoading: Boolean by mutableStateOf(true)

    init {
        loadBooks()
    }

    private fun loadBooks() {
        searchBooks("android")
    }

     fun searchBooks(query: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
            if (query.isEmpty()){
                return@launch
            }
            try {
                when(val response = repository.getBooks(query)){
                    is Resource.Success -> {
                        list = response.data!!
                        if (list.isNotEmpty()) isLoading = false
                    }
                    is Resource.Error -> {
                        isLoading = false
                        Log.e("Network", "searchBooks: Failed Getting books", )
                    }
                    else -> {isLoading = false}
                }
            }catch (exception: Exception){
                isLoading = false
                Log.d("Network", "searchBooks: ${exception.message.toString()}")
            }
        }

     }
}
```

I'll leave the project public so you guys can check it out for more of an understanding
Github Link: https://github.com/OEThe11/ReadersApp

P.S. you would have to create a login (takes 30 sec), but once you do, you'll have access to the app immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is occurring because of `JsonSyntaxException java.lang.NumberFormatException` while the JSON response is getting parsed from the API. This is because the `averageRating` field in the `VolumeInfo` data class is declared as Int but the response can contain floating point values.

If you change `averageRating` field type from `Int` to `Double` in the `VolumeInfo` data class, the exception would no longer occur.

I suggest you to debug your code in such cases.

Comment: Thank You. That did work. How would I go about debugging my code? Do just do logd and the debugger option for Android? And how would you approach debugging in general? Thanks again.

Comment: @OEThe11 I went through your data layer code and put breakpoints in the code while running the app and that's how I get to know about the error. 
Generally, whenever there are crashes or other reproducible issues, I use debugging otherwise I put Logs whenever the issues are not reproducible (for eg. if an error is occurring only in case of some data change).
Hope it helped!